# Volumes on OpenShift without starting in an empty dir

Tags: docker, openshift

Is it possible to use in OpenShift as volume claim a docker VOLUME which already contains data? f.e. My docker file already builds an application with an config folder and this folder contains already files.

Target: Connect the OpenShift pod with this data in a persistence volume.

My actual problem is, that a persistence claim on OpenShift creates an empty dir.

What is the way to go for this problem? Do I really have to copy all the files in the persistence claim?

Answer (score 0):

A persistent volume can be declared as pre bound, such that it will only match a persistent volume claim with certain name in a specific project. See:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html#persistent-volumes-volumes-and-claim-prebinding